# Can you only have one string after !=

Tags: python

I'm just writing some small code and I'm not able to make this work, I am only able to have one string which is e.g boy or girl but I would like to have both, do I have to make a separate elif statement or can I somehow put girl in there as well

```py
    gender = input("Are you a boy or a girl? : ")

    if (gender != "boy"):

    print("Get out of here you mutant")

    exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to have 3 conditions:

```
if gender == 'boy':
    print ('You are a boy')
elif gender == 'girl':
    print ('You are a girl')
else:
    print("Get out of here you mutant")
```

Or you can do like that:

```
if gender in ('boy', 'girl'):
    print('You are a {}'.format(gender)
else:
    print("Get out of here you mutant")
```

In the second script you check if `gender` is a girl or a boy and if so it puts `gender` variable in the print output string.

Comment: You probably should also convert gender to lower case (`gender.lower()`) in `if` to account for situations where user inputs something like `Boy` or `BOY`